# How to test if a property is not present with Spring Boot JacksonTester?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test, assertj

When using a `@JsonTest` with an `@Autowired` `JacksonTester`, how can I test if a certain property is not present?

Suppose you have this object to serialize:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class MyTestObject {
    private Boolean myProperty;

    // getter and setter
}
```

With this test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@JsonTest
public class MyTestObjectTest {

    @Autowired
    private JacksonTester<MyTestObject> tester;

    public void testPropertyNotPresent() {
        JsonContent content = tester.write(new MyTestObject());
        assertThat(content).???("myProperty");
    }
}
```

Is there a method to put in the `???` so that it validates that the property is *not* in the resulting JSON when it is `null`?

As a workaround, I currently use:

```
    assertThat(content).doesNotHave(new Condition<>(
            charSequence -> charSequence.toString().contains("myProperty"),
            "The property 'myProperty' should not be present"));
```

But that is not exactly the same of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JSON path assertions to check values, however, you can't currently use it to check if the path itself is present. For example, if you use the following:

```
JsonContent<MyTestObject> content = this.tester.write(new MyTestObject());
assertThat(content).hasEmptyJsonPathValue("myProperty");
```

It will pass for both `{"myProperty": null}` and `{}`.

If you to test that a property is present but `null` you'll need to write something like this:

```
private Consumer<String> emptyButPresent(String path) {
    return (json) -> {
        try {
            Object value = JsonPath.compile(path).read(json);
            assertThat(value).as("value for " + path).isNull();
        } catch(PathNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new AssertionError("Expected " + path + " to be present", ex);
        }
    };
}
```

You can then do the following:

```
assertThat(content.getJson()).satisfies(emptyButPresent("testProperty"));
```

Incidentally, your string assertion could also be simplified to:

```
assertThat(content.toString()).doesNotContain("myProperty");
```

Comment: Not true, unfortunately. If the property is present with a `null` value, the test does not fail.

Comment: That's strange, I thought I'd tested it. Have you got a sample project I can try?

Comment: I created a sample project at https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/json-property-not-present. You'll see that `testJsonWithNull_doesNotContain` does fail, while `testJsonWithNull_hasEmptyJsonPathValue` does not fail if `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` is not present on the `TestObject`

Comment: I see now, you want to check that the value is `null`, but the property name is still in the JSON. I've updated the answer to show how that can be done. If you want to raise a Spring Boot issue we can look at adding another assertion method.

Comment: It is in fact the inverse. I want to ensure in my unit test that the property is _not_ present. I want to be sure that the `@JsonInclude` is present on `TestObject`. The test should _fail_ if `@JsonInclude` is _not present_.

Comment: Thanks for raising the issue. As of Boot 2.2 you'll be able to do `assertThat(content).doesNotHaveJsonPath("myProperty")`.

Comment: Today, I found that `doesNotHaveJsonPath` always fails. That also means that `hasJsonPath` always succeeds, even with fantasy paths, except when the given path is syntactically invalid.